# Compiler claims pointer is const when it is not used

Tags: c, gcc

My compiler gives this warning:

> > inlinedata.h:9:6: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’

```
int  inline_data_receive(char *data,int length);
```

I don't understand why it claims 'data' is a const pointer when it is not written as a const char*.

Comment: How are you calling it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's saying that the *argument* (the data that you are passing in) is `const`. It might be a string literal, for example. So instead of doing this:

```
ret = inline_data_receive("hello", len);
```

do this

```
char str[] = "hello";
ret = inline_data_receive(str, len);
```

You need to do it this way since the function is not guaranteeing that it won't modify the input string.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler is complaining that you are passing a `const char*` value to a value that is labeled as `char*`.  Essentially the following

```
const char* c = ...;
inline_data_receive(c, strlen(c));
```

The compiler is complaining that `c` is `const char*` but needs to be `char*` to line up with the argument `data`